# docker-compose service list changes among branches: Service has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm working on a new service on my stack.

So when I work on the `new-service` branch, I have in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  app:
    image: whatever
  new_service:
    image: whatever
```

I do `docker-compose up` and start working.

But then I sometimes need to make hot fixes on the `master` branch, where `new_service` is not there.

When I try to do `docker-compose up`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file is invalid because:
Service new_service has neither an image nor a build context specified. At least one must be provided.
```

I guess, I could edit my `docker-compose.yml` file to add fake `new_service` entry only to start my server, but that's not an acceptable solution to me.

Shouldn't `docker-compose` re-read the service list on every start? Or can't I at least force the refresh like `docker-compose up --reset`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok my bad.

`docker-compose` does work as expected, but I had a

```
service:
  new_service:
    command: yarn dev
```

entry in my `docker-compose.override.yml` which is `.gitignore`d, hence the error.

I wanted to delete the question, but then I considered others may do the mistake, and landing here would help them too.

We'll see. :-)